# Can I use an alphanumeric value as a numerical value in Google spreadsheets?

Tags: spreadsheet

Here's what I want to do:

I work in a school and the children's progress is measured is levels. E.g. 2c, 3b, 4a, etc.

In the Google spreadsheet is there a way for it to display the actual level (e.g. 3c) but somehow know that 3c < 3b < 3a < 4c < 4b < 4a etc?

This would work well if it could know that, for example, from 2a to 3a is a whole level's progress and from a 3c to a 3a is 2 sublevel's progress.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make a lookup-table with two columns as follows:

```
progress - value
-----------------
2c - 1
3b - 2
4a - 3
etc.
```

Then you can use lookup functions to work with later.

Answer (score 0):

Cells
a1: 2a
a2: 2b
a3: =(left(A1;1)*10+code(right(A1;1)))-(left(B1;1)*10+code(right(B1;1)))

You can change the values in cells a1 and a2. The progress/degress of whole levels will be visible in intervals of 10. The progress/degress will be visible in intervals of 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following remarks

- sub levels are small caps
- 'c' is the lowest sublevel, otherwise

  - replace "c" in all the formulas with for instance "d"
  - replace in all the formulas the 3 with 4
- replace ; with , if this is needed for your country settings
- Cell A1, the value: 2c
- Cell A2, the value: 3a

The formula to re-code:

`Cell(B1)     =left(A1;1)*3+(code("c")-code(right(A1;1)))`

`Cell(B2)     =left(A2;1)*3+(code("c")-code(right(A2;1)))`

The result is a value you can subtract:

```
Cell(B3)  =B2-B1
```

> The result is: 5   sub levels improvement

To encode it to Level and Sub level improvements

```
Cell(B3)  =if(B2=B1;"=";if(B2<B1;"-";"+")&floor(abs(B2-B1);3)/3&"L"&mod(abs(B2-B1);3)&"S")
```

> The result is: +1L2S

If Cell A1=  4b, Cell A2=  1c,  then the result will be: -3L1S